# Apache Open meetings run locally for development

Tags: java, openmeetings

I am aiming to use Open meetings in my project. Before doing that, I was starting with some UI colour changes and check the system on my local machine. For doing this, I cloned the Git repository https://github.com/apache/openmeetings .

After this, executed the command: `mvn clean install -PallModules`
*Working with Java version 11 and mvn version 3.6.3

After the execution, build generates successfully:

[image]

After this, as mentioned in git, I followed following steps:

- go to openmeetings-server/target directory
- extract apache-openmeetings-x.x.x.tar.gz (or apache-openmeetings-x.x.x.zip for windows) to new directory
- enter to this new directory and execute ./bin/startup.sh (./bin/startup.bat for Windows)

Results says, Tomcat started. Also with command `netstat -lntp`, I can see port 5080 is occupied by a java jar. [image]

But, the problem is when i open `http://localhost:5080`, it successfully redirects me to `http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/` but shows site can't be reached. 
[image]

This is very weird, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Build instructions and helpful commands are here

https://openmeetings.apache.org/BuildInstructions.html

I would recommend to use `unpacked` build

OM at http://localhost:5080/openmeetings works  for me as expected

(I would recommend to use it at https://localhost:5443/openmeetings overwise Camera&Microphone will be blocked by browser)

Is it possible your request is being blocked by FW?

P.S. I'm one of OpenMeetings devs

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the reply. Trying to compile again with unpack version, i get this error. PS. I have not made any code changes till this time:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
 at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
 at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
 at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(Modules.java:247)
 at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSourceFile(JavaCompiler.java:837)
 at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Implic
`

Comment: What java version is this? please share bigger stack trace :)

Comment: This is for java 11

Comment: It is impossible to say what is wrong with such small part of stacktrace. Both local and Jenkins builds are green ...